# How to configure fonts in Chrome menus?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Chrome v41 and I've found one day that the fonts(size and type of font) of in my menu and bookmarks changed without my intended configuration.

Would anyone tell me how to change the fonts of Chrome's menu and bookmarks?

Comment: Try this chrome://settings/search#font into your browser url and then just change it.

Comment: Steps with pictures: http://www.bbc.co.uk/accessibility/guides/change_fonts/browser/win/chrome/

Comment: What you suggest is to change the font of the web page. However, what I want to know is how to change the font of UI instead of web page.